# How to register custom voter in Symfony KNP Menu Bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, knpmenubundle

so I decided to use the KnpMenuBundle in my Symfony project, but in order for the menu to work as I intend to, I added 2 lines to the  `/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Matcher/Voter/RouteVoter.php`.

So I know it's a bad practice to change the contents of the vendor folder. My question is, how to I apply these changes? I'm guessing I have to create my own Voter class, extend the RouteVoter and somehow register it with Symfony. Nowhere on the internet could I find how to do that.

Any ideas? Thanks, Mike.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To register a custom voter you must create a customVoter in your project and register it as a service.

Your voter should look something like this

```
class RegexVoter implements VoterInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RequestStack
     */
    private $requestStack;

    /**
     * @param RequestStack $requestStack
     */
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function matchItem(ItemInterface $item)
    {
        $childRegex = $item->getExtra('regex');

        if ($childRegex !== null && preg_match($childRegex, $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getPathInfo())) {
            return true;
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Register it as a service like this

```
menu.voter.regex:
    class: AppBundle\Menu\Matcher\Voter\RegexVoter
    arguments: [ '@request_stack' ]
    tags:
        - { name: knp_menu.voter }
```

Then you have to instantiate your voter in your menuBuilder

```
private $regexVoter;

public function __construct(RegexVoter $regexVoter)
{
    $this->regexVoter = $regexVoter;
}
```

In my example my voter get the item extra `regex` to work.

I think you must modify and use your own logic.

I hope this will help you

Comment: I think that if you use ESI, you should use this regex : `preg_match($itemRegex, $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest()->getPathInfo())`

Comment: You don't have to inject the voter  into the menuBuilder because DI takes care of it when you tag it.

Comment: @BillH dependencies injection wasn’t here when I wrote this answer. But your right

Comment: Note: since Symfony 5.3, you can use `#[AutoconfigureTag('knp_menu.voter')]` in your class instead of registering it in `services.yaml`. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html